# Monitor cpu usage, gpu memory usage, swap memory usage and ram usage

Tags: linux, performance, resources, monitoring

I am looking for a tool on Linux (ubuntu specifically)

Something like Procpath but to monitor every resource I listed

EDIT:

I need to monitor a specific process (Like a docker container) And to automatically write everything into a file. I am not sure that htop will do, but maybe I am wrong

Comment: Are you looking for a single tool to monitor all these resources?

Comment: @Ajithkumar_sekar ideally - yes, but I understand that there can be no such tool

Comment: you can use top command to see CPU, RAM memory, SWAP memory usage. For GPU alone I guess you want to install vendor-specific tools

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Gnome System Monitor**

This tool is very simple and that's user interface is very cool simple.

Also I'm using this tool for linux.